# Navigation View app:menu build gradle error

Tags: gradle, build, navigationview

I am trying to use Navigation View in Drawer Layout, but I keep getting errors when building the file.

Here's what my xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This leads to a build gradle error. My menu looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
            android:title="Bookmark" />

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
            android:title="Save" />

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
            android:title="Search" />

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

When I remove app:menu from the navigationView,the error goes away. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My fix was that I needed to add app:headerLayout="@layout/my_header_layout" as well.